# Why does my second called ball in pygame flicker?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pygame, instance

I made a `class Ball` with two instances: `ballOne` and `ballTwo`. When I call `ballTwo.update()` and then `ballOne.update()`, the last called ball sometimes disappears on some frames, like it sometimes flickers on and off. Can someone please help?

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

displaySize = (800,600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)

g = 50
dt = 0.05

Cd = 0.01
m = 5

class ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, r,ax,ay, color):

        self.Fx = 0
        self.Fy = 0

        self.Dx = 0
        self.Dy = 0

        self.ay = ay
        self.ax = ax

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.color = color

        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy



    def update(self):

        self.x, self.y = self.physics()
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(round(self.x)),int(round(self.y))), self.r)
        pygame.display.update()





    def physics(self):


        self.x +=self.vx*dt
        self.y +=self.vy*dt

        self.vy += self.ay*dt
        self.vx += self.ax*dt

        self.ay = self.Fy/m
        self.ax = self.Fx/m

        self.Fy = m*g - self.Dy
        self.Fx = -self.Dx

        self.Dy = Cd*self.vy*abs(self.vy)
        self.Dx = Cd*self.vx*abs(self.vx)

        if self.x <= self.r:
            self.vx *= -0.7

        if self.x >= displaySize[0]- self.r:
            self.vx *= -0.7

        if self.y <= self.r:
            self.vy *= -0.7

        if self.y >= displaySize[1] - self.r:
            self.vy *= -0.7

        return self.x, self.y


ballOne = ball(100,100,50,-100,30,0,0,red)
ballTwo = ball(500,500,-75,0,45,0,0,green)
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill(blue)
    ballTwo.update()
    ballOne.update()
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your code does very strange: Methods are missing `def` and `update()` is missing `self` parameter, `class` should be lowercase.

Comment: hopefully its better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `pygame.display.update()` for each object, which is causing the flickering. Remove those calls and use `pygame.display.flip()` in the game loop.

I also recommend separating the updating and drawing of objects. Later, you may want to draw the objects in a different order than you want to update the objects.

A typical game loop does the following:

1. Process events
2. Calculate new position of objects
3. Draw next frame
4. Display frame

In Python, the game loop might look like this:

```
objects = [ballOne, ballTwo]
while True:
    # 1. handle events

    # 2. update objects
    for object in objects:
        object.update()

    # 3. draw frame
    screen.fill(blue)
    for object in objects:
        object.draw()

    # 4. display frame
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```